# Joining two columns in the same data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to add one column at the end of another column. I have included a picture that kind of demonstrates what I want to achieve. How can this be done?

For example, in this case I added the age column under the name column

[image]

Dummy data:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan},
 'age ': {0: 35, 1: 56, 2: 22, 3: 16},
 'name': {0: 'andrea', 1: 'juan', 2: 'jose ', 3: 'manuel'},
 'sex': {0: 'female', 1: 'male ', 2: 'male ', 3: 'male '}}
```

Comment: Please post the data itself, not a picture of it.

Comment: @learnerB add a code example.....

Comment: @Chris I cannot post the data itself as it is classified. Sorry about that

Comment: Do you want age data column to put it under the name column data?

Comment: @Jimmys well the issue is that I don;t really know how to achieve it

Comment: @learnerB wait, what? If it's classified why did you post it as an image then?

Comment: @Jimmys correct! I cannot figure out how to do this correctly

Comment: @Ch3steR that is not my actual data. I made it up on excel as an example

Comment: @learnerB okay, Can you post `df.to_dict()` of the dummy data, it would be easier for everyone to reproduce locally, rather transcribing an image.

Comment: @Ch3steR done! Sorry about that.

Comment: It looks like [**`pd.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). You can try this `df.melt(id_vars=['sex'], value_vars=['name', 'age ']).drop(columns = 'variable')`

Comment: @paytonM No problem. Please go through [How to make good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html). If your data is in the `DataFrame` `df`:

```
# Split out the relevant parts of your DataFrame
top_df = df[['name','sex']]
bottom_df = df[['age','sex']]

# Make the column names match
bottom_df.columns = ['name','sex']

# Append the two together
full_df = top_df.append(bottom_df)
```

You might have to decide on what kind of indexing you want. This method above will have **non-unique indexing** in `full_df`, which could be fixed by running the following line:
`full_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pd.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and drop `variable` column using [**`df.drop`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
                   'age ': {0: 35, 1: 56, 2: 22, 3: 16},
                   'name': {0: 'andrea', 1: 'juan', 2: 'jose ', 3: 'manuel'},
                   'sex': {0: 'female', 1: 'male ', 2: 'male ', 3: 'male '}})

df.melt(id_vars=['sex'], value_vars=['name', 'age']).drop(columns='variable')

      sex   value
0  female  andrea
1   male     juan
2   male    jose
3   male   manuel
4  female      35
5   male       56
6   male       22
7   male       16
```